# PHP Array to JSON Array using json_encode() and how can json parse android;

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I have an php array and encode it with json_encode($arr).

I want to parse this Json in android using JSONObject.

but how can i parse it and print only names on text_view like Rohan(all names) print on text_view.

```
[["Rohan","example1.com"],["Ashok","example2.com"]]
```

Can i convert it into like this

`{ "students": [{"Rohan":"example1.com"}]`}

Answer (score 0):

First, let's name our array like this:

**edit**

It's a good practice to add a header specifying the content type, before actually doing the encode:

```
header('Content-type: application/json')
json_encode(array('students' => $arr));
```

This way, you will get this:

```
{ "students": [{"Rohan":"example1.com"}]}
```

Instead of what you are getting right now.

To get the names from your JSONObject in Android, you would need to cycle trough the array, and pick one by one. Assuming you are getting your JSON form PHP in the form of a String, you could try something like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mJSON);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("students");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject current = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if (!current.getString("student_name").isEmpty()) {
        mTextView.setText(current.getString("student_name"));
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got this { "students": [["Rohan","example1.com"]]} from your answer. Not look like this { "students": [{"Rohan":"example1.com"}]}.

Comment: Can you post the code where you generate your array on PHP, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to  to encode the json with php this way to fit your needs :

```
<?php 
$json='{
    "students": [
        {
            "Rohan": "example1.com"
        },
        {
            "Ashok":"example2.com"
        }
    ]
}';
var_dump($json);

$students=array(
    "student"=>array(
        array("Rohan"=>"example1.com"),
        array("Ashok"=>"example2.com")
        )
    );
var_dump(json_encode($students, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

But i think it's a bit weird to do it this way as you have to create arrays containing only one key. I think herrmartell architecture is clearer.
Cheers !